# Bash while read loop: output never changes; being cached?

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop, audio-player

***FINAL ANSWER:

```
dbus-monitor --profile "interface='net.sacredchao.QuodLibet',member='SongStarted'" |
while read -r line; do
  sleep 1
  echo -e "$(grep '~filename=' $HOME/.quodlibet/current | sed 's/~filename=//')\n$(python2 -c "import sys, urllib as ul; print ul.unquote_plus(sys.argv[1])" "$(quodlibet --print-queue | sed 's|file://||g')")" > $HOME/Dropbox/Playlists/queue
done
```

There were issues with race conditions and clobbering a file with more than one write, and I also replaced the echo -e with a python command since, quodlibet being made with python, it was probably parsed into the parsing I don't want with python in the first place. It all works now. I've finished giving quodlibet functionality that most music players already have: a queue that actually survives the program crashing and doesn't require constant tinkering and babysitting to just play each song exactly once. *sigh*

------------------------Original Question:

I'm using Arch Linux, and I've made a script that's supposed to save quodlibet's queue every time a song finishes/starts playing. Everything works EXCEPT for one thing (so you don't have to check all those sed commands for errors or anything). If I run all this stuff manually in a terminal, without any while loop or DBus--just manually writing to the files every time I notice a song ending--it works fine. Once I put it in the while loop, it still writes to the file every time a song starts, but it writes the exact same file every single time until I restart the script. I think it's caching the outputs of these commands and not ever updating that cache.

So, let's spell this out: quodlibet has its currently playing song and the queue of what to play next. Here's the script:

```
while read -r line; do
  grep '~filename=' $HOME/.quodlibet/current \
  | sed 's/~filename=//' > $HOME/Dropbox/Playlists/queue
  echo -e "$(quodlibet --print-queue | sed 's|%|\\\x|g' | sed 's|file://||g')" \
  >> $HOME/Dropbox/Playlists/queue
done <<< "$(dbus-monitor --profile "interface='net.sacredchao.QuodLibet',member='SongStarted'")"
```

Every time a song changes, what's supposed to happen is those two commands write the now-playing song and the queue to a file. What happens instead is every time a song changes, those two commands write what WAS the now-playing song and queue the FIRST time that while loop wrote to the file.

So let's say the now-playing is track 1 and tracks 2 thru 10 are in the queue. The script writes that to the file.

Then, track 1 finishes. Now, now-playing is track 2 and the queue is tracks 3 thru 10. However, even though the loop notices the song change and writes to the file, what it writes instead is track 1 as now-playing and tracks 2 thru 10 as the queue. Again. And on and on, and before you know it, it's playing track 10 and the queue is empty, but the file still has all 10 tracks in it.

I tried running the exact same commands inside the loop manually, myself, in a terminal outside the loop, immediately after a song change, while the loop script was running. The file would reflect what it was supposed to. But then when the song changed again, the loop would catch that and rewrite all 10 tracks, again. In other words, these exact commands only don't do what I want when they're inside the loop. SOMEthing is definitely being cached and never updated, here.

EDIT: It looks like I need to clarify some things.

1) Despite how this shouldn't be, my script behaves the exact same way whether it's:

```
while read -r line; do
  grep '~filename=' $HOME/.quodlibet/current \
  | sed 's/~filename=//' > $HOME/Dropbox/Playlists/queue
  echo -e "$(quodlibet --print-queue | sed 's|%|\\\x|g' | sed 's|file://||g')" \
  >> $HOME/Dropbox/Playlists/queue
done <<< "$(dbus-monitor --profile "interface='net.sacredchao.QuodLibet',member='SongStarted'")"
```

Or:

```
dbus-monitor --profile "interface='net.sacredchao.QuodLibet',member='SongStarted'" |
while read -r line; do
  grep '~filename=' $HOME/.quodlibet/current \
  | sed 's/~filename=//' > $HOME/Dropbox/Playlists/queue
  echo -e "$(quodlibet --print-queue | sed 's|%|\\\x|g' | sed 's|file://||g')" \
  >> $HOME/Dropbox/Playlists/queue
done
```

2) I tested a simpler version out before bringing the more complex stuff in. Here's a script I made:

```
while true; do
  echo "$(cat /tmp/foo | sed 's/b/n/g')"
done
```

I tried changing the file /tmp/foo in the middle of that loop running, just as the output of the quodlibet commands changes on its own, and it updated just fine. The output changed like it should.

This wasn't what I started with, but it's the last one I made before moving on to the actual script. You'll see it incorporates everything I'm doing except for 4 things: quodlibet, the dbus command, >saving or >>appending to a file, and the while-read combo. One of those is making the output constantly the same no matter what changes in the environment, and I think we can rule out quodlibet, since, as I said before, running those commands manually works fine.

EDIT 2: Welp, I haven't been scrolling down on the file, but I did just now. This issue just got more complicated but probably easier to solve. It's not writing the exact same output every time at all. It's somehow skipping the line that overwrites the file--the one that starts with grep--and JUST appending the output of the second line, the echo -e.

EDIT 3: And now I'm stumped again. When I copy and paste the exact two lines right out of the while loop and into a bash Terminal, they do what I want. But in the while-loop, the first grep command never actually writes to that file. I thought maybe it was inexplicably eating the first command, so I tried adding an empty echo beforehand:

```
dbus-monitor --profile "interface='net.sacredchao.QuodLibet',member='SongStarted'" |
while read -r line; do
  echo
  grep '~filename=' $HOME/.quodlibet/current \
  | sed 's/~filename=//' > $HOME/Dropbox/Playlists/queue
  echo -e "$(quodlibet --print-queue | sed 's|%|\\\x|g' | sed 's|file://||g')" \
  >> $HOME/Dropbox/Playlists/queue
done
```

but it's still eating that first grep. Why won't it save the file?

EDIT 4: I've confirmed that the grep command is definitely outputting the correct output, but just won't write it to the file.

Comment: If you don't bother with the file and just run the `quodlibet` command in the loop do you see the correct queue output or the original? Because that's the real question here. Does that command work there or not. Similarly, does the `current` file change in real-time the way you expect.

Comment: Are you sure it's actually running the loop when you think it is? That `<<< "$(dbus-monitor ... )"` part should capture the entire output of the `dbus-monitor` command and feed it to the loop all at once, rather than line-at-a-time as songs finish. Try adding `echo "line = '$line'" at the top of the loop, and see what happens.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes, those commands do change if I don't bother with the file. I said that a few times in the OP. (wow, I wish the enter key wasn't bound to posting the comment; that took me by surprise)

Comment: @GordonDavisson What I have there is what I cobbled together from searching for how to do the DBus thing and then for how to run a while loop without piping it into a separate fork every iteration (which is something I tried at first, which produced the exact same results as what I have now). All I know is that what I have does in fact run the loop again each time the song changes. I tested that already.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Good catch. Yeah, that's a here-string not process substitution. I don't know how that is going to work for a process that doesn't end (as I assume the monitor doesn't).

Comment: Does using `< <(dbus-monitor ...)` instead of `<<< "$(dbus-monitor ...)"` change things?

Comment: @EtanReisner That also did not change the behavior. So far, all 3 versions of the while loop have identical behavior for me.

Comment: Dump your grep output to stdout. Dump everything to stdout. Debug it by ripping it apart piece by piece. If your grep output isn't working, then there's either a problem with your query or the file doesn't exist (at that point in time) in the state you expected it to.

Comment: Why are you using `-e` on the second `echo` output? Why are you using `echo` at all? Does using `quodlibet --print-queue | sed 's|%|\\\x|g' | sed 's|file://||g' >>  $HOME/Dropbox/Playlists/queue` have different behavior?

Comment: Add `set -x` to the script, capture every output to a variable and *then* print them to the file *and* standard error/output (make sure to quote your variable expansions).

Comment: I'm using echo -e because quodlibet --print-queue uses URL character codes, like %20 instead of space, but the enqueue commands that would queue those files back up do not accept %20, so I have to replace stuff like %20 with a space, or %21 with a !, or etc., and the best way to do that that I've found is to turn the % into a \x and run it through echo -e. The echo command is doing what I want it to, though. The only problem is the grep won't write to the file.

Comment: My best guess is race conditions. Even terminal IO would slow down the process enough to prevent them. `( tail -f ~/Desktop/temp ) | while read -r line ; do printf "$line\n" > ~/Desktop/temp2 ; echo "foobar" >> ~/Desktop/temp2 ; done`. No issues there. Try adding a `sleep 1` as your first loop command.

Comment: RE: urldecoding, just use a python oneliner: `python -c "import sys, urllib as ul; print ul.unquote_plus(sys.argv[1])" $urlencoded`

Comment: I think you nailed it. Adding that sleep 1 at the beginning makes it so now, it ONLY writes the grep and the echo can't append. So, I tried adding ANOTHER sleep 1 between the grep and the echo, but it STILL can't append. How can I get both commands to write in one go? Thanks for the python tip. I feel better using python, since quodlibet probably prints it that way because it's also using python.

Comment: For the record, you're probably clobbering a file that was just modified by doing this, but you would just want to formulate your loop so that it does exactly one write. Combine them into one command or use a variable: `echo -e "$(grep '~filename=' $HOME/.quodlibet/current | sed 's/~filename=//')$(quodlibet --print-queue | sed 's|%|\\\x|g' | sed 's|file://||g')" > $HOME/Dropbox/Playlists/queue`. Also, this is seriously gross. I think there's a better way to do whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: See my answer for what might turn out to be a cleaner script. I would also recommend editing your question and answer so that it could provide utility for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

In an effort to decouple the specific thing you're trying to do from the problem you perceive, I'm going to suggest trying out some independent commands before trying to use anything fancy.

```
while read -r line ; do
    echo $line
done <<< $(yes)
```

Note that this will never output anything. The input provided by `$(yes)` never completes so the outer loop will never print anything. This was pointed out by at least one of the comments to your main post.

Instead of using a capture variable, try piping the output directly to your loop. I can't say this will work for you, but it at least fixes one of the obvious problems of streaming output to a while loop.

```
yes | while read -r line ; do
    echo $line
done
```

Based on the other debugging efforts here, the problem appears to be a race condition between the signal to dbus about the song transition and the writing of the new "current" song to disk. In an effort to provide a more complete solution (untested of course), here is what I might start with:

```
function urldecode() {
    python -c "import sys, urllib as ul; print ul.unquote_plus(sys.argv[1])" "$@"
}

dbus-monitor --profile "interface='net.sacredchao.QuodLibet',member='SongStarted'" | \
while read -r line; do
    sleep 1 # Adjust as necessary to preventing race conditions
    $CurrentSongFile=$(grep '~filename=' $HOME/.quodlibet/current | sed 's/~filename=//')
    $SongFileQueue=$(urldecode "$(quodlibet --print-queue)") | sed 's_file://__g')
    printf "$CurrentSongFile\n$SongFileQueue" > $HOME/Dropbox/Playlists/queue
done
```

Comment: I was doing exactly that at first, but it produced the same output that I'm getting now, at the same times. I switched to what I'm doing now because when I tried to get help, a lot of people were having trouble with variables in a while loop until they switched from what you're suggesting to what I'm doing now. But that said, it doesn't matter, because I get the exact same unwanted behavior either way.

Comment: Anyway, independent commands. I did do that first, and it worked until I factored while-read and quodlibet into the mix. I'll edit my post with that info.

Comment: Could you simplify your problem? I'm willing to bet most of us don't have your setup ready to debug. As a debugging step, try `dbus-monitor ... | while read -r line; do printf "$line" ; done`. Use printf and wrap the variable in quotes to ensure you get raw output. After you've verified your have formulated your loop correctly, then add in other things.

Comment: Done. I modified my test script to be `dbus-monitor --profile "interface='net.sacredchao.QuodLibet',member='SongStarted'" | while read -r line; do echo "$(cat /tmp/foo | sed 's/b/n/g')"; done`.
The output still changed as intended. So, that means the fault does not lie with while-read or the dbus command.

Comment: I'm going to recommend we open a chat and I'll post back the results of our debugging efforts. Maybe this link works? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95874/question-33860537

Comment: I don't think I have 20 reputation yet. It says I need that to chat in there. Also, yes, it prints a newline, and I just tried adding file saving to the mix (`echo "$(cat /tmp/foo | sed 's/b/n/g')" > /tmp/bar`) and that also worked as intended.

Comment: Working on it... I think I can enable it for you. Looks like I can't. Too bad. Could you print `grep '~filename=' $HOME/.quodlibet/current` inside the loop to make sure it does what you expect?

Comment: Hahahahahaha, immediately after your comment about how I can't join chat is "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" Nice system, StackOverflow. Anyway, I just made a major breakthrough. I'll elaborate in edit #2.

Comment: Another upvote or two and you can chat ;P. Make sure your grep command is working as intended.

Comment: Don't dump the grep output to a file, dump it to stdout.

Comment: Good idea. I tried that and the output in stdout was exactly what it should've been. So, why isn't it being written to the file, even though the other command is being appended just fine? Do while-loops have something against overwriting files???